# Warning: Missing argument 1 for mock

Tags: symfony, mocking, behat

I'm trying to make a service mock:

```
$this->mocker->mockService(
    'manager.mikrotik',
    new AtoumAdapter(
        '\MyBundle\Services\MikrotikManager'
    )
);
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   mock\MyBundle\Services\MikrotikManager::__construct(), called in
>   vendor/rezzza/mock-extension/src/Adapter/AtoumAdapter.php on line 45
>   and defined in vendor/atoum/atoum/classes/mock/generator.php(183) :
>   eval()'d code line 22

Where is my mistake?

---

Now I resolve using orphanize:

```
$this
    ->mocker
    ->mockService(
        'manager.mikrotik',
        new AtoumAdapter(
            '\MyBundle\Services\MikrotikManager',
            function ($generator) {
                $generator->orphanize('__construct');
            }
        )
    );
```

Here class __construct:

```
public function __construct($em,$mikrotikIp, $mikrotikUser, $mikrotikPassword)
```

Comment: Can you include `MikrotikManager` class declaraiton? It seems like you're skipping a parameter for this in `AtoumAdapter`.

Comment: public function __construct($em,$mikrotikIp, $mikrotikUser, $mikrotikPassword)